# Staggered horizontal Recyclerview Android, help needed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, customization, android-gridlayout, staggeredgridlayoutmanager

[image: Custom recyclerview layout manager]

What I'm trying to achieve is to create a RecyclerView which scrolls horizontally, and the items should appear in different sizes similar to the drawing started from 0 position and so on. What i have tried so far is:

1. played with position of items on adapter onBindViewHolder, but that's not a solution and it doesn't solve my problem.
2. implemented StaggeredGridLayoutManager as layout manager `StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);`, but the spanCount blocks me.
3. GridLayoutManager scrolls vertically, not horizontal

Is there any lib or guidelines on how to design a specific RecyclerView Layout Manager ? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Google lib can help you  to achieve [Staggered horizontal Recyclerview](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)

Comment: Do you have experience with it, does it takes the row count span automatically or you define it at the begin ? Thank you!